# How do I traverse through a dataframe and get polarity score of existing text(transcript) so I have 1 row per id in python?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I am able to traverse through files in a directory with my script but unable to apply the same logic to when all the transcriptions are in a table/dataframe. My earlier script -

```
import os    
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

files = glob('C:/Users/jj/Desktop/Bulk_Wav_Completed_CancelsvsSaves/*.csv')
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
# use dict comprehension to apply you analysis
data = {os.path.basename(file): sid.polarity_scores(' '.join(pd.read_csv(file, encoding="utf-8")['transcript'])) for file in files}
# create a data frame from the dictionary above
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
df.to_csv("sentimentcancelvssaves.csv")
```

How do I apply the above to the below table where

```
 dfo
    Out[52]: 
                InteractionId             Agent  Transcript  
    0      100392327420210105      David Michel  hi how are you          
    1      100392327420210105      David Michel  yes i am not fine       
    2      100390719220210104    Mindy Campbell  .,xyz..        
    3      100390719220210104    Mindy Campbell  no       
    4      100390719220210104    Mindy Campbell  maybe    
                      ...               ...  ...       ...      ...
    93407  300390890320200915    Sandra Yacklin  ...   
    93408  300390890320200915    Sandra Yacklin  ...     
    93409  300390890320200915    Sandra Yacklin  ...
```

So as you see here, I have a column interaction id which is unique. I my final data set to give me 1 row per id and I require to get the polarity scores of the sentiments attached to that id.

Desired output for 100390719220210104 -

```
        InteractionId             Agent     Transcript       Positive     Compound

2      100390719220210104    Mindy Campbell  xyz no maybe     0.190   0.5457
```

How can I do this for all interaction id? I was able to do it when i had to apply my script to all transcripts csvs in a directory and iterate through them all. However, how can I apply that to a dataframe where all the data is in one place and not different csvs

Comment: would the transcript for Mindy be `.,xyz.. no maybe`?

Comment: @Zev yes. sorry about that. I made the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So rather than looping through the files, you are looping through the unique InteractionIds. You can get that using: `for interaction_id in dfo['InteractionId'].unique()`

And then you are joining the values in that column for that ID which you can get by:
`' '.join(dfo[dfo['InteractionId'] == interaction_id]['Transcript'])`

Putting it together you have:

```
import os
from glob import glob

import nltk
import pandas as pd
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

dfo = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'InteractionId': [
            100392327420210105,
            100390719220210104,
            100390719220210104,
            100390719220210104,
        ],
        'Transcript': ['hi how are you', '.,xyz..', 'no', 'maybe'],
    }
)

sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
# use dict comprehension to apply you analysis
data = {
    interaction_id: sid.polarity_scores(
        ' '.join(dfo[dfo['InteractionId'] == interaction_id]['Transcript'])
    )
    for interaction_id in dfo['InteractionId'].unique()
}

# create a data frame from the dictionary above
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
df.to_csv("sentimentcancelvssaves.csv")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. for some reason I receive a keyerror for 'Transcript' even though it is exactly the same in my column. Can you please share your output

Comment: It doesn't provide any output but produces the file. `neg neu pos compound
`
`1.0039071922021E+017 0.524 0.476 0 -0.296`

Comment: Can you show me the traceback for your error?

Comment: Any chance your column is named `'Transcript  '` rather than `'Transcript'`?

Comment: list(dfo.columns)
Out[70]: 
['InteractionId',
 'Agent',
 'RowNumber',
 'InitiatedDate',
 'Transcript',
 'WrapupCode']

Comment: did you update my code to use `dfo` rather than `df`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236105/discussion-between-zev-and-newinpython).